# Error while recording native application using HTTPS over SSL via JMeter

Tags: jmeter, native

When trying to record mobile native application using JMeter, getting below error :-

2015/04/18 10:43:22 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [50309] Empty response to http over SSL. Probably waiting for user to authorize the certificate for uat.omegaservices.carrental.com:443
2015/04/18 10:43:22 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [50311] Empty response to http over SSL. Probably waiting for user to authorize the certificate for uat.omegaservices.carrental.com:443
2015/04/18 10:43:22 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [50310] Empty response to http over SSL. Probably waiting for user to authorize the certificate for uat.omegaservices.carrental.com:443
2015/04/18 10:43:22 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [50312] Empty response to http over SSL. Probably waiting for user to authorize the certificate for uat.omegaservices.carrental.com:443

Can anyone please help me how to resolve  this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see "Add security exception" dialog as per [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) guide cleaning your browser history should be quite enough to resolve the problem.

Comment: Hi, But i am trying to record an mobile native application